# Obtaining object reference for a method using getattr

Tags: python, function, object, reference, getattr

Say, I have the following `class` called `Test` with a `method` called `start`

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         pass
...     def start(self):
...         pass
...
```

Now, I have a standalone independent `function` called `func`

```
>>> def func():
...     print 'this is a func and not a method!!!'
... 
>>>
```

[1]
Now, `t.start` is a `method` of an `instance of __main__.Test` which belong to `0xb769678c`

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.start
<bound method Test.start of <__main__.Test instance at 0xb769678c>>
>>>
```

[2]
`func` is a `function` which belong to the location `0xb767ec6c`

```
>>> func
<function func at 0xb767ec6c>
>>>
```

Now, we can extract the `__module__` from `t.start` and `func` by using builtin `__module__`. Not surprisingly, `func` and `t.start` belong to the same `module` i.e. `__main__`

```
>>> func.__module__
'__main__'
>>> t.__module__
'__main__'
>>>
```

[3]
Now, lets store `__module__` for `t.start` in a variable `obj`

```
>>> obj = __import__(t.start.__module__)
>>> obj
<module '__main__' (built-in)>
>>>
```

Now, I use `getattr()` to get the `func` handle `<function func at 0xb767ec6c>` for function `func` as follows and the output of `getattr()` is the `identical` to [2]

```
>>> print getattr(obj, 'func')
<function func at 0xb767ec6c>
>>> 
>>> print getattr(__import__('__main__'), 'func')
<function func at 0xb767ec6c>
>>>
```

#### Question:

How do I use `getattr()` and the module name [3] to get the handle of `Test.start` [1] which should be `<bound method Test.start of <__main__.Test instance at 0xb769678c>>`

When I tried using `getattr()` on `'t.start'` I got the following `Traceback`

```
>>> print getattr(obj, 'Test.start')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Test.start'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print getattr(__import__('__main__'), 'Test.start')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Test.start'
>>>
```

In other words, I have two data with me. They are

1. `__import__('__main__')`
2. The sting `'Test.start'`

Now, how do I get the handle for `t.start` (note the `instance` here) which should be `<bound method Test.start of <__main__.Test instance at 0xb769678c>>`

Comment: The `getattr` function requires an attribute name as second operand. You can't use `Test.start` you must do two calls `getattr(getattr(the_module, 'Test'), 'start')`

Comment: @Sangeeth I've rewritten several times my answers because the first ones were very confused. I think that now it is more logically developped , hence readable. Take care that I modified it in depth , maybe after  your first reading (if you ever read it ....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question(s), but I think this does what you want:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def start(self):
        pass

def func():
    print('this is a func and not a method!!!')

t = Test()

module = __import__(t.start.__module__)

print(vars(module)['Test'].start)
print(vars(module)['func'])
print(vars(module)['t'].start)
```

(Python 3) output:

```
<function Test.start at 0x00E52460>
<function func at 0x00E524F0>
<bound method Test.start of <__main__.Test object at 0x008DF670>>
```

Comment: Would you say that each item output in your example is an "object reference" as used in this quote: [`The actual parameters (arguments) to a function call are introduced in the local symbol table of the called function when it is called; thus, arguments are passed using call by value (where the value is always an object reference, not the value of the object).`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Comment: Yes, the values shown being looked up by name in `vars(module)` are all object references in the same sense as the term is being used in the quote. `vars(<object>)` is equivalent to `<object>.__dict__`, which in this case is the module object's attribute dictionary used for mapping the module's attribute names to their corresponding values (which are object references).

Answer (score 1):

```
obj = __import__(t.start.__module__)    

test_class = getattr(obj, 'Test')

print getattr(test_class, 'start')
```

I'm not sure if you need it straight from the module (or even if that is possible) :/

You could also use:

```
obj = __import__(t.start.__module__)

print obj.__dict__["Test"].__dict__["start"]
```

but you asked for `getattr()` so...

Answer (score 0):

I wondered why you wrote `obj = __import__(t.start.__module__)`
I think it's to hold a name for the main module, in order to have the possibility to obtain the objects in the module's namespace as attributes of the module thanks to the **getattr( )** function.

I inform you that you don't have to do this trick.
**globals( )** is a dictionary that represents the global namespace of the main space.
Then you can write, for example, `globals()["func"]` to obtain the object **func**

I also inform you that there is another way than with `getattr(N,"xyz")` to obtain an object **xyz** in the namespace of the object **N** thanks to its name `xyz` ,
it's by the `__dict__` method:
`N.__dict__` gives access to the namespace of the object **N**

---

I wonder if your problem doesn't lies in a subtlety of Python that induced you in an error.

In your question, at a place you wrote `t.__module__` and at another place you wrote `t.start.__module__` .
For the two cases, the result is the same and equal to `"__main__"`

However,
1) **t** has no attribute of name `__module__`
2) **t** has even no attribute of name `start` !
If you print `t.__dict__` you'll see the result is `{ }`  !

**start** isn't really belonging to the namespace of the instance **t** because it belongs in fact to the namespace of **Test**

The following code proves these affirmations:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def start(self):
        pass

y = Test()
y.ku = 102

print 'y.__dict__',y.__dict__
print 'Test.__dict__',Test.__dict__
```

result

```
y.__dict__ {'ku': 102}
Test.__dict__ {'start': <function start at 0x011E11B0>,
'__module__': '__main__',
'__doc__': None,
'__init__': <function __init__ at 0x011E1170>}
```

.

The reason why the expressions `t.__module__`  and `t.start.__module__`  give answers anyway is explained by this citation:

> A class **instance** has a namespace implemented as a dictionary which is
>   the **first place** in which attribute references are searched.
>   When an
>   attribute is not found there, and the instance’s **class** has an
>   attribute by that name, the search continues with the class
>   attributes.
>
> http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#index-55

Hence:
1) **t** has no attribute of name `__module__` then Python searches for it in the class of **t**
2) **t** has no attribute of name `start` then Python searches for it in the class of **t**

.

Well, so, Python goes to the class of **t** to find the values of `t.__module__` and `t.start.__module__`
This mechanism, described by the above citation, can be observed with the following code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def start(self):
        pass

t = Test()

print 'getattr(t,"start")'
print getattr(t,"start")

# result is
getattr(t,"start")
<bound method Test.start of <__main__.Test instance at 0x011DF288>>
```

I mean that Python answers that the attribute of **t** whose name is `"start"` is  **Test.start** , not **t.start** !

.

Thereby, from the fact that `t.start.__module__` is `"__main__"`, it seems to me that you may have believed that  **t.start** is belonging to the module namespace, and hence you should be able to write something similar to `getattr(obj,"func")` to obtain the object **start**

But it is false.
You can't find the method **start** (I write the METHOD) in the global namespace = namespace of the module, since it is in the namespace of **Test**.  You must attain it, as a method, through the instance or the class or through the class itself.

---

One more thing.
I precised : the METHOD, because I believe that the method **t.start** is based on a **FUNCTION** that is something different from it and **that lies in the module's namespace**. In reality, a method is a wrapper of pointers pointing to an instance and to this global namespace's function:

> If you still don’t understand how methods work, a look at the
>   implementation can perhaps clarify matters. When an instance attribute
>   is referenced that isn’t a data attribute, its class is searched. If
>   the name denotes a valid class attribute that is a function object, a
>   method object is created by packing (pointers to) the instance object
>   and the function object just found together in an abstract object:
>   this is the method object. When the method object is called with an
>   argument list, a new argument list is constructed from the instance
>   object and the argument list, and the function object is called with
>   this new argument list.
>
> http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects

Well what I want to underline is that it seems a function (not a method) exists somewhere, on which a method is based.

What I believe is that this function lies in the module namespace and that it's why `Test.__dict__["start"]`
gives
`<function start at 0x011E40F0>`
while
`getattr(Test,"start")`
and `getattr(t,"start")`
give
`<unbound method Test.start>`
and `<bound method Test.start of <__main__.Test instance at 0x011DF530>>`
without localizing the bound and unbound methods.

So, in my opinion, as far as I have correctly understood the doc (which is not explaining these points very well, I find, by the way) a method is a wrapper, and is based on **a real function that lies in the module namespace**, and that's why `t.start.__module__` and `Test.start.__module__` are `"__main__"`

It may seem a little weird that there exists a function in the module namespace  that doesn't appear among the attributes of the module when we print them with `globals()` :

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def start(self):
        pass

def func():
    print 'this is a func and not a method!!!'

t = Test()

print '* globals()["func"]'
print globals()["func"]
print id(globals()["func"])
print "===================================="
print '* Test.__dict__["start"]'
print Test.__dict__["start"]
print id(Test.__dict__["start"])
print '----------------------------------------------'
print '* getattr(Test,"start")'
print getattr(Test,"start")
print id(getattr(Test,"start"))
print '----------------------------------------------'
print '* getattr(t,"start")'
print getattr(t,"start")
print id(getattr(t,"start"))
print "===================================="
print globals()
```

result

```
* globals()["func"]
<function func at 0x011C27B0>
18622384
====================================
* Test.__dict__["start"]
<function start at 0x011DEFB0>
18739120
----------------------------------------------
* getattr(Test,"start")
<unbound method Test.start>
18725304
----------------------------------------------
* getattr(t,"start")
<bound method Test.start of <__main__.Test instance at 0x011DF418>>
18725304

{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>,
'__package__': None,
't': <__main__.Test instance at 0x011DF418>,
'func': <function func at 0x011C27B0>,
'Test': <class __main__.Test at 0x011DC538>,
'__name__': '__main__',
'__doc__': None}
```

But the fact is that we indeed see a `Test.__dict__["start"]` function whose address 18739120 is different from the bound and unbound methods address 18725304.
Moreover, I don't see which other explanation could explain the totality of the facts exposed.

There's in fact nothing weird in the fact that a function that didn't receive any assigned name doesn't appear in the module namespace.
It is an internal function, necessary to Python, not at the disposal of the programmer, that's all.

---

Concerning **func**, using all the methods you employed:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def start(self):
        pass

def func():
    print 'this is a func and not a method!!!'

t = Test()
print 'func --->',func
print id(func)

print '\nobj = __import__(t.start.__module__)  done\n'
obj = __import__(t.start.__module__)

print '* globals()["func"]'
print globals()["func"]
print id(globals()["func"])
print '* obj.__dict__["func"]'
print obj.__dict__["func"] 
print "* getattr(obj, 'func')"
print getattr(obj, 'func')
print "* getattr(__import__('__main__'), 'func')"
print getattr(__import__('__main__'), 'func')
```

result

```
func ---> <function func at 0x011C2470>
18621552

obj = __import__(t.start.__module__)  done

* globals()["func"]
<function func at 0x011C2470> # <== address in hexadecimal
18621552                      # <== address in decimal
* obj.__dict__["func"]
<function func at 0x011C2470>
* getattr(obj, 'func')
<function func at 0x011C2470>
* getattr(__import__('__main__'), 'func')
<function func at 0x011C2470>
```

.

Now taking apart your methods using `obj` :

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def start(self):
        pass

print 'Test.start -->',Test.start
print id(Test.start)
print '----------------------------------------------'
print '* Test.__dict__["start"]'
print Test.__dict__["start"]
print id(Test.__dict__["start"])

print '* getattr(Test,"start")'
print getattr(Test,"start")
print id(getattr(Test,"start"))
print '\n'


print 't.start -->',t.start
print id(t.start)
print '----------------------------------------------'
print '* t.__dict__["start"]'
try:
    print t.__dict__["start"]
    print id(t.__dict__["start"])
except KeyError as e:
    print 'KeyError :',e

print '* getattr(t,"start")'
print getattr(t,"start")
print id(getattr(t,"start"))
```

result

```
Test.start --> <unbound method Test.start>
18725264
----------------------------------------------
* Test.__dict__["start"]
<function start at 0x011E40F0>
18759920
* getattr(Test,"start")
<unbound method Test.start>
18725264


t.start --> <bound method Test.start of <__main__.Test instance at 0x011DB940>>
18725264
----------------------------------------------
* t.__dict__["start"]
KeyError : 'start'
* getattr(t,"start")
<bound method Test.start of <__main__.Test instance at 0x011DB940>>
18725264
```

Until now, I had seldom used `getattr( )`.

I realize on these results that `getattr( )` gives results in a specific manner: the attribute **start** is described as a method, bound or unbound according if it is attained through an instance or through a class.

However, only `__dict__` gives precise information on the real attributes of an object.
Thus, we see that **start** isn't really in the namespace of the instance, but only in the namespace of the class.
It is described as being a function when it is as element of the namespace `Test.__dict__`  and as being a method when given as an attribute through `getattr( )`. There are no addresses given in this last case.

The use of the **vars( )** function gives the same results.